# prestashop get products of an order

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I get all data that I want from delivery address with this:

```
public function getOrderShippingCost($params, $shipping_cost)
    {
        global $smarty;
$url = Tools::getHttpHost(true).__PS_BASE_URI__;
$address = new Address($this->context->cart->id_address_delivery);
        $state = new State ($address->id_state);
        $country = new Country ($address->id_country);

echo $address->postcode;

        echo $address->country;

        echo $address->address1;

        echo $address->address2;

        echo $state->name;

        echo $country->iso_code;
```

And the result is fine, but now how can I get the products of an order?

I try this code:

`$products = $params['cart']->getProducts(true);`

but the result of this is `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Cart as array in`

If I try with something like this:

```
$order = new Order($this->context->order->id_order);
```

the result are two error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Context::$order in /var/www/prestashop/modules/mycarrier/mycarrier.php on line 325

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/prestashop/modules/mycarrier/mycarrier.php on line 325
```

How can get the products?

Answer (score 4):

You already use:

```php
new Address($this->context->cart->id_address_delivery);
```

So I think you can use:

```php
$products = $this->context->cart->getProducts(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the order detail object to get the products of the particular order id in prestashop.

```
$ProductDetailObject = new OrderDetail;
$product_detail = $ProductDetailObject->getList($order_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Presta order data are stored in object $order

You can access it ex. with function than you can hook anywhere you need.

```php
public function yourHOOK($params)
    {
        $order = $params['objOrder'];
        $products = $order->getProducts();

        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'order'=> $order,
            'order_products' => $products,
      ));

         return $this->display(__FILE__, 'confirmation.tpl');
    }
```

So we assign `$order` and `$products` variables to the template, returning it in the end.
Be sure `.tpl` file is located inside your module’s folder.

You can read more here > https://nemops.com/prestashop-order-confirmation-resume/#.ZDV2jvbP34Y